# php artisan migrate stuck at the beginning of the command

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan, artisan-migrate

[MacOS 10.14.0]
When I create a new project (`Laravel new blog`)
Then create a table in MySQL (`create database blog`)
And then update my .env file with the correct userame, password and database.

After creating a project, I will run `php artisan migrate`
But my terminal stays empty, I can type in my terminal. But it won't do anything.

My storage/logs folder is empty.

I have 2 default migrate files in my database/migrations folder.

`php migrate list` works

What can it be?

Comment: Have you tried restarting the system? Seems like you have another process attached to MySQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, I found out that there was something wrong with my MySQL server. I reinstalled MySQL with brew. The latest version of 8 and the latest version of 5.7.*. Both didn't work, because of the following conflict: `Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so, 2): image not found`.

So the whole time, everything in my .env file was correct but my MySQL was broken. I also confirmed that by trying to connect with the app 'Sequel Pro'. And as I thought, it gave me the same conflict.

How I fixed the problem:

- Remove all MySQL/MariaDB packages via brew (if you have installed them with brew like me)
- Install `MySQL Community Server 5.7.*` from the official mysql.com website (you can google that file).
- Add MySQL to your path `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin`
- Go to: `System Preferences -> MySQL -> press 'Start MySQL Server'`
- Change your temporary password with a new one `mysqladmin -uroot -p[temporary password] password '[new password]'`

Good luck!

---

**EDIT FEBRUARY 26 2019:**
I found a problem with changing the random generated password. I was using MySQL Community Server 5.7.25 and the random generated password was: `_>9mxWc9a!0.`. When I was trying to change the default password with the command above. I was given the following error: 
`-bash: !0: event not found` 
If you have the same error as I did or something similar, try the following:

- Enter the following command in your terminal: `mysqladmin -uroot -p password '[new password]'`
- When you press enter, it will ask you for a password. Now enter the random generated password that was given to you by the MySql Community Server at installation in a prompt.

It should be working now!

Answer (score 7):

For me it helped just to restart local database.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Docker and getting this error on the host machine, try running the migration in the container cli.

Comment: This is helpful as the error may not get back to you on the host machine. Running the command directly in the container CLI returned the error on console that was making it hang on the host machine.

Answer (score 0):

did you connected the laravel project to the database from .env file ?

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=DATABASE_NAME
DB_USERNAME=DATABASE_USERNAME
DB_PASSWORD=DATABASE_PASSWORD
```

Comment: As I said on the second line of my question, yes I did update my .env file will the correct configuration to connect to my database.

Comment: its probably something from the connection between your app and the database, please try restart your mysql service and check the root user and password again and run php artisan migrate again

Comment: I recommand for mac to use laradock its great docker server for laravel and make everything more easy for you check it out : 
http://laradock.io/

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 5.8 with SQLite.

My problem wasn't with larvel but with DB browser for sqlite. I had to open and close the program for the migrate to finish its process.